# Generic Knapsack Expression Assignment

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression, knapsack-problem

Im trying to create a modified knapsack function that can take a collection of objects and compare any 2 of its number based values and find the most optimized configuration.

Ive gotten the algorithm to work if I already know the objects type and properties but Id like to make a generic version that can work on any object.

The algorithm works by first ordering the collection by the property that represents the resourceCost (the value that that needs to be minimized), and then iteratively adding the largest cost resources to the sack until the sack it completely filled up by the resourceSize (the value that takes up "space" in the sack)

Recognizing, that some of the larger cost resources, could have minimal sizes thus leaving the possibility that when the sack is filled, it could still be optimized further, the last step is to recursively remove the smallest sizes while maintaining that the sack remains at least 100% full. (Im purposely allowing 1 item to overfill the sack to make sure the sack size is 100% utilized)

An example of the codes usage might be:

```
listOfBuildings.KnapSack(300, building => building.NumRooms, building => building.Distance);
```

This is answering the question "Return the least amount of buildings that are closest to home that have a total sum of at least 300 rooms"

**So here is my question:**

Notice right under the foreach loop I commented out `currentSackSize += item.resourceSize;` this is because obviously this isnt the right syntax. Since Im using T as a generic type. How do I return the same value from "item" that I specified as the resourceSize?

So anyways here is code:

```
   public static IEnumerable<T> KnapSack<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, float sackSize, Expression<Func<T, object>> resourceCost, Expression<Func<T, object>> resourceSize) {
        source = source.OrderBy(resourceCost);

        int currentSackSize = 0;
        bool useLastIteration = true;
        List<T> sack = new List<T>();

        foreach(T item in source) {
            //currentSackSize += item.resourceSize;
            if(currentSackSize <= sackSize) {
                sack.Add(item);
            } else {
                if(useLastIteration) {
                    sack.Add(item);
                    useLastIteration = false;
                    if(currentSackSize > sackSize) {
                        sack = OptimizeSack(sack, resourceSize, sackSize);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return sack;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> OptimizeSack<T>(IEnumerable<T> sack, Expression<Func<T, object>> resourceSize, float sackSize) {
        int currentSackSize = sack.Sum(resourceSize);
        int minValue = sack.Min(resourceSize);

        if((currentSackSize - minValue) > sackSize) {           
            source = sack.OrderBy(area).Skip(1); //drop the smallest value from the sack
            return OptimizeSack(sack, sackSize);
        } else {
            return sack;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use a normal for loop? As in that `source[i]` corresponds to `resourceSize[i]`.

Comment: resourceSize is a lambda expression, as far as I know you cant apply indexing [] to it.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I was presuming it would return an Enumerable.